# Tweak for Informix Query (Cisco Call Data Agent State)

Tags: sql, informix

It appears I have come to a dead end.  I am pulling my data from a Informix database (cisco call center data) and am trying to write a query that displays the duration for each agent state.  There are 4 columns in the table(agentstatedetail) I am pulling from: agentid, eventdatetime, eventtype, and reasoncode.  The objective of the query is to get the time duration for each eventtype.  The query runs fine, however there is one major flaw.  When an agent state (for the same agentid) happens simultaneously(same eventdatetime for the next eventtype) my query returns duplicates because in my subquery I have eventdatetime>asd1.eventdatetime.  Basically I need to create a second eventdatetime column and move each row up by 1 where agentid=agentid.  I tried that using the MIN function however as I stated above this logic is flawed because some events happen simultaneously.  I have pasted my code below.  I have tried creating an index table however since I am unable to write to the DB for me that is not an option.  **Another way to put it is how do I say take the next row no matter what where agentid=agentid?**    Any suggestions would be very helpful.  Thank you!

**PhotoLinks:** 
https://goo.gl/photos/sqM8GYdDZLrD3jAAA: QueryOutcome
https://goo.gl/photos/5E68jvwadjA5y5zZA: Wanted Outcome - i.e. 21 reason code = lunch

**Table Schema:** 
(agentID: Identifier of the agent whose state has changed, int,NOT NULL,Primary Key)

(eventDateTime: Date and time that the agent state changed. datetime year to fraction (3), NOT NULL, Primary Key)

(eventType: Event that triggered the agent state change: smallint, NOT NULL, Primary Key)

(reasonCode: Null if a reason code is not configured, smallint, NOT NULL, Primary Key)

```
select res.resourcename,

DATE(asd1.eventdatetime) as Date,
asd1.eventdatetime as starttime,
asd2.eventdatetime as endtime,
((asd2.eventdatetime-asd1.eventdatetime)::interval second(9) to second::char(10)::int) as duration,

   asd1.reasoncode as reasoncodenum

from agentstatedetail asd1

   join agentstatedetail asd2
   on asd1.agentid=asd2.agentid
     and asd2.eventdatetime = (select min(eventdatetime)
                               from agentstatedetail
                               where agentid = asd1.agentid
                               and eventdatetime>asd1.eventdatetime)
   left join resource res on asd1.agentid=res.resourceid

where asd1.agentid=asd2.agentid
```

Comment: Not an answer, but why don't you store all codes and descriptions in separate tables? Then you can join and get the changes, now all queries must be updated whenever a code change.

Comment: @ jarlh I have no write permissions, this DB is managed by somebody else offsite unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

So the given schema is:

```
create table agentstatedetail
  (
    agentid integer,
    eventdatetime datetime year to fraction(3),
    eventtype smallint,
    reasoncode smallint,
    primary key (agentid,eventdatetime,eventtype,reasoncode)
  );
```

You only have the next **eventtype**:

```
1   'Logged In' 
2   'Not Ready' 
3   'Ready' 
4   'Reserved' 
5   'Talking'
6   'Work' 
7   'Logged Out'
```

You wan't a report for the transition between **eventtype**, even if the durantion is 0 second.

The problem is that when you have 0 seconds you'll get duplicates.

Are these rules correct:

- After **Logged In** you always be in **Not Ready**;
- After **Not Ready** you always be in **Ready**;
- After **Ready** to pass to **Not Ready** you have to **Reserved** first.

If all these rules are correct the test case below should work:

```
CREATE TABLE agentstatedetail (
    agentid         INT,
    eventtype       INT,
    eventdatetime   DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION
);

INSERT INTO agentstatedetail VALUES (1, 1, CURRENT - 1 UNITS HOUR);
INSERT INTO agentstatedetail VALUES (1, 2, CURRENT);
INSERT INTO agentstatedetail VALUES (1, 3, CURRENT);
INSERT INTO agentstatedetail VALUES (1, 4, CURRENT + 1 UNITS HOUR);

SELECT
    t1.agentid                              AS agent_id,
    t1.eventtype                            AS src_event_type,
    t2.eventtype                            AS dst_event_type,
    t1.eventdatetime                        AS start_time,
    t2.eventdatetime                        AS stop_time,
    (t2.eventdatetime  - t1.eventdatetime ) AS durantion
FROM
    agentstatedetail t1 JOIN agentstatedetail t2
        ON  t1.agentid  = t2.agentid 
            AND t2.eventdatetime  = (
                SELECT MIN(eventdatetime )
                FROM agentstatedetail
                WHERE agentid  = t1.agentid 
                AND eventdatetime  >= t1.eventdatetime 
                AND NOT (
                        (t1.eventtype  = eventtype )
                    OR  (t1.eventtype  = 1 AND eventtype  = 3) 
                    OR  (t1.eventtype  = 3 AND eventtype  = 2)
                    OR  (t1.eventtype  = 2 AND eventtype  = 4)
                )
            )
WHERE
    NOT (
            (t1.eventtype  = t2.eventtype )
        OR  (t1.eventtype  = 1 AND t2.eventtype  = 3) 
        OR  (t1.eventtype  = 3 AND t2.eventtype  = 2)
        OR  (t1.eventtype  = 2 AND t2.eventtype  = 4)
    );
```

Comment: @ Ricardo I have added the schema for the table to the question.  I am not really sure what you mean by join on eventtype conditions.  The eventtype is the same though. The query is not taking into account events that happen simultaneously. So its not matching up some of the events correctly.

Comment: @ Ricardo - I have added links on the question I posted with the outcomes and the results that I want.  I hope that helps with understanding the question.  Thank you.

Comment: @Jason For this case `UNIQUE` must be sufice.

Comment: @ Ricardo Unfortunately distinct/unique does not work in this case because Ready and Reserved have the exact same times, when in fact the duration for Ready =0 where Reserved = X.  Anything else I can try?

Comment: @Jason You're right, I wasn't thinking about the duration. In that case you either put some logic in you're query or consider using a temporary table, if your result set is not that big. To add some logic if you no that after a Not Ready you always have a Ready that gives you 0 duration you can add to your where clause `AND (asd1.eventtype!= 'NR' AND asd2.eventtype!='R')`. Our use the HAVING clause where duration greater than 0.

Comment: @ Ricardo I believe I figured it out. I need to write something in the where clause when asd1.eventtype ='Ready' and asd2.eventtype='talking' then asd2.eventdatetime =asd1.eventdatetime. So then the duration will be 0. Is that possible? My table has over 2M lines of code so adding a table would not be plausible. I added in 'and'(asd1.eventtype='ready' AND asd2.eventtype='talking'' which works but just removes the 0 duration for ready state when I want it in my data...

Comment: @Jason The real reason you are not getting 0 durantion is because in your `JOIN` condition you say `eventdatetime>asd1.eventdatetime`. Check the edit answer.

Comment: unfortunately I cant write to the database.  I am just going to forgo selecting 0 durations.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jason if you only have `CONNECT` privilege you can create a temporary table to see the test case. Nonetheless, you can adapt the query to your real table to see if it works the way you want.